# Trying to cast string to number returns NaN

Tags: javascript

I'm confused... I have a number as a string (`'3'`), and I want it to become a normal Number-type number. If I go into any console and do `Number('3')`, it'll return `3`.

However, in this code it returns `NaN`:

```
const attr = "rating='3'";
const [attrName, attrValue] = attr.split('=');
// if the attrValue is a number, cast it as such
if (!Number.isNaN(attrValue)) {
    const numAttr = Number(attrValue);
    console.log('num: ', numAttr, attrValue.length, attrValue.charCodeAt(0));
}
```

I confirm that the first char code of the number string is 39, which is single apostrophe, and its length is 3, so no sneaky hidden chars.. The `numAttr` value is `NaN` though. It also does go into the if statement, which presumably tells me that it can, in fact, become a number?

Comment: Your `attrValue` is `"'3'"` and not `"3"` which is what you probably expected. You need to remove the single quotes before casting.

Comment: Go into the console and do `Number("'3'")`, since that would be equivalent.

Comment: Please try this: `const numAttr = +attr.split('=')[1].split("'")[1];`

Comment: I see... but then why does `Number.isNaN("'3'")` return `false`? If it couldn't be converted to a string I'd expect it to return `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the single Quotes around the number. You can use the `replace()` function for this:

```js
const attr = "rating='3'";
let [attrName, attrValue] = attr.split('=');
const para1 = attrName;
const para2 = attrValue.replace(/'/g, '');

console.log(para1, para2);
console.log('isNAN()?',isNaN(para2))
```

**isNaN = is not a Number?**